# Parsing a tab-delimited text file to replace columns with one vertical list (Python)

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and I know this is a pretty basic question. I have a text file with columns of data. I want to remove the columns and make it one long list.

I have the following code:

```
for line in open('feddocs_2011.txt', 'r'):
    segmentedLine = line.split("/t")
    print segmentedLine
```

This seems to create a separate string for each line, but I think I may need to loop through each of those new strings to split those next. I thought it would have put everything following a tab on a new line. I tried the following, but got an error message that "list" doesn't have a split function.

```
while segmentedLine:
    item = segmentedLine.split("\t")
    print item
```

Thanks very much for any input.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do.  Can you give some (small) sample input and output?

Answer (score 5):

You've got the lines split properly in the first loop. What you want to do then is have a second for loop to iterate over each tab-separated item. That'll look like this:

```
for line in open('feddocs_2011.txt', 'r'):
    segmentedLine = line.split("\t")
    for item in segmentedLine:
        print item
```

Or more concisely, without the temporary variable:

```
for line in open('feddocs_2011.txt', 'r'):
    for item in line.split("\t"):
        print item
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this worked! Thanks to everyone who responded so quickly!

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
x = [line.split('\t') for line in open('file.txt')]
```

and you can join the lists, if you want:

```
sum(x, [])
```

[Edit]

if your file only have tabs (no spaces) you can simply do:

```
x = open('file.txt').read().split()
```

Comment: I don't know how the text is formatted for sure... If he also wants to convert data to int or to float he don't need to remove trailing \n or \r

Comment: using `sum()` is very inefficient (O(n^2)) on large lists

Comment: @simon sometimes simpler is better... I know sum is intended to numbers, but it works nicely for small lists :)

Comment: @JBernado -- depends what you're doing, I suppose, but I would reckon 12 times slower is probably to be avoided! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python/953050#953050)

Comment: @simon Python may be 12(or more) times slower than C... But we still use it! Sum is good and the most readable for small lists.

Answer (score 1):

So you have

```
foo<tab>bar<tab>baz
bla<tab>bla<tab>bla
```

and you want it to be

```
foo
bar
baz
bla
bla
bla
```

Right?

Then you can just do

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read().replace("\t", "\n")
```

Now `text` is a single string. If you want a list of all the items instead (`["foo", "bar", "baz", "bla", "bla", "bla"]`), use

```
text = f.read().replace("\t", "\n").split("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, what you're after is:

```
import itertools
print '\n'.join(list(itertools.chain(*[line.strip().split(',') for line in open('feddocs_2011.txt', 'r')])))
```

Answer (score 0):

> put everything following a tab on a new line

If this is all you want, why not just use the [str.replace](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function?

```
for line in open('feddocs_2011.txt', 'r'):
    segemented_line = line.replace('\t', '\n')
    print(segmented_line)
```

If, for some reason, you want to keep the tabs:

```
for line in open('feddocs_2011.txt', 'r'):
    segemented_line = line.replace('\t', '\t\n')
    print(segmented_line)
```